# Gnome extensions stay in the list after being removed

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I've got a little issue with gnome shell extensions. After installing some of them, I understood I didn't like them and decided to remove them. The extensions themselves (their folders in `/home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`) were deleted successfully. However, the deleted extensions were *not* removed from the list of installed extensions at [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/). They also were not removed from the list in gnome-tweak-tool.

So now in my list I have a bunch of extensions that I have already deleted. The funny thing is that I can't reinstall them too, since both the gnome-tweak-tool and the website think they are still there. This isn't a big deal of course, but I find it a little annoying.

Reinstalling gnome-tweak-tool didn't help.

Is there a way to somehow update the status of installed extensions?

Comment: Did you log out, and then log in again?

Comment: @Alistair, yes of course,  multiply times =)

Comment: Do you happen to have the gnome-shell-extensions package installed? The two places where extensions can be placed, as far as I know, is /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ and $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/

Answer (score 2):

**How to remove one or all Gnome-shell extension(s) completely**

Open terminal: (from app menu or by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T)

Then type: sudo su -
and type your password and press enter

[image]

then type this command:

```
cd /home/"your user account"/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
```

[image]

then type this command to see all your installed extensions: ls

[image]

then type this command to remove each or extension you really want to remove it completely:

```
rm -r name-of-extention
```

for example : rm -r dash-to-dock@yyy.gmail.com/

[image]

and press : Alt+F2 then type “r” yes simple just one r

Ok it done.

You can check extensions.gnome.org to be sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

Go to installed extensions on extensions.gnome.org and click the X symbol in the circle to the right of the extension to uninstall it. The ON/OFF switch only disables it.

[image]

Comment: That's the first thing I've tried. The button doesn't do anything.

Comment: Upvoted. Works for me. (Pop!_OS 22.04)