# Gnome 3.10: Can I get the old system status menu back without downgrading?

Tags: gnome

As the title specifies.

I prefer the system status menu I am used to in Gnome 3.8:

[image]

Not the new one that comes with Gnome 3.10:

[image]

Can I achieve this without downgrading to Gnome 3.8?

Comment: Try: sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback I solved the problem with this.

Comment: Did system status menu get disappeared completely or only network manager icon get disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal & type this

`sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`

If you just want to disable extensions then refer this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202123/gnome-extensions-stay-in-the-list-after-being-removed)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit here, a bit clearly!

Comment: _If you just want to disable extensions_ It's not even related

Comment: Can you elaborate what does ' old system ' mean in this question?

Comment: @GuestWithAQuest refers to Gnome 3.8

Comment: which feature you want from Gnome 3.8?

Comment: Did you read the question?